# How do I show if the following is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm learning about the concept of linear transformation and I am having some trouble applying it. 
I know that for T to be a linear transformation, then $T(x+w) = T(x) + T(w)$ and $T(rx) = rT(x)$

Now, I am trying to apply this theory to the following problem but I have no clue how to approach it.

Let's say I have a set of equations:
$y_1 = 2x_2$
$y_2 = -9x_3$
$y_3 = -6x_1$

How do I approach this kind of question and solve it?

Comment: What does "solve it" mean? And what does your title mean?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is your question. The title suggests you have to prove that something is a linear transformation. The actual question is related to solving a set of equations. Where do LTs come in?

Answer (score 1):

As you said - "I know that for $T$ to be a linear transformation, then $T(x+w)=T(x)+T(w)$ and $T(rx)=rT(x)$".

$x=(x_1; x_2; x_3)$.

$T(x)=(2x_2; -9x_3; -6x_1)$.

Let's apply it:

1. $$T(x+w)=T(x)+T(w)$$  where $x$=($x$<sub>1</sub>; $x$<sub>2</sub>; $x$<sub>3</sub>) and $w$=($w$<sub>1</sub>; $w$<sub>2</sub>; $w$<sub>3</sub>).

We need to prove that if we use the given transformation, both results are the same.

$T(x+w)$=$T$(($x$<sub>1</sub>; $x$<sub>2</sub>; $x$<sub>3</sub>)+($w$<sub>1</sub>; $w$<sub>2</sub>; $w$<sub>3</sub>))$=$ $T$(($x$<sub>1</sub>+$w$<sub>1</sub>; $x$<sub>2</sub>+$w$<sub>2</sub>; $x$<sub>3</sub>+$w$<sub>3</sub>))$=$($2$($x$<sub>2</sub> +$w$<sub>2</sub>); $-9$($x$<sub>3</sub>+$w$<sub>3</sub>); $-6$($x$<sub>1</sub>+$w$<sub>1</sub>))$=$($2x$<sub>2</sub>$+2w$<sub>2</sub>; $-9x$<sub>3</sub>$-9w$<sub>3</sub>; $-6x$<sub>1</sub>$-6w$<sub>1</sub>).

$T(x)+T(w)=T$(($x$<sub>1</sub>; $x$<sub>2</sub>; $x$4<sub>3</sub>))+$T$(($w$<sub>1</sub>; $w$<sub>2</sub>; $w$<sub>3</sub>))=($2x$<sub>2</sub>; $-9x$<sub>3</sub>; $-6x$<sub>1</sub>)+($2w$<sub>2</sub>; $-9w$<sub>3</sub>; $-6w$<sub>1</sub>)=($2x$<sub>2</sub>+$2w$<sub>2</sub>; $-9x$<sub>3</sub>$-9w$<sub>3</sub>; $-6x$<sub>1</sub>-$6w$<sub>1</sub>).

Both sides are equal so "$T(x+w)=T(x)+T(w)$" is fulfilled.

2. $$T(rx)=rT(x)$$ where $x$ $=$ ($x$<sub>1</sub>; $x$<sub>2</sub>; $x$<sub>3</sub>).

$T(rx)=T$($r$($x$<sub>1</sub>; $x$<sub>2</sub>; $x$<sub>3</sub>))$=T(rx$<sub>1</sub>; $rx$<sub>2</sub>; $rx$<sub>3</sub>)$=(2rx$<sub>2</sub>; $-9rx$<sub>3</sub>; $-6rx$<sub>1</sub>).

$rT(x)=rT((x$<sub>1</sub>; $x$<sub>2</sub>; $x$<sub>3</sub>))$=r(2x$<sub>2</sub>; $-9x$<sub>3</sub>; $-6x$<sub>1</sub>)=$(2rx$<sub>2</sub>; $-9rx$<sub>3</sub>; $-6rx$<sub>1</sub>).

Both sides are equal so "$T(rx)=rT(x)$" is fulfilled.

Both 1. and 2. are fulfilled, so $T(x)=(2x$<sub>2</sub>; $-9x$<sub>3</sub>; $-6x$<sub>1</sub>) is a linear transformation.

Comment: Here is a quick guide on MathJax to format your posts: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are having problem in writing matrix of transformation. Note that, 
$y_1= 0x_1 +2x_2 + 0x_3$
$y_2=0x_1+0x_2-9x_3$ 
$y_3=-6x_1+0x_2+0x_3$ 
Can you write the matrix of transformation A now? 
$T(x) =[y_1\; y_2\; y_3]^T=Ax$, where $x=[x_1\; x_2 \;x_3]^T$ From here, you can prove that $T$ is a linear transformation.